# Adding related data to ActiveRecords without using a join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, scope, rails-activerecord

My Rails 4 app has a `User` model, a `Link` model, and a `Hit` model. Each `User` has many `Link`s, and each `Link` has many `Hit`s. Occasionally, I want to display a list of the `User`'s `Link`s with the number of `Hit`s it has.

The obvious way to do this would be to loop over the links and call `link.hits.count` on each one, but this produces N+1 queries. So instead, I wrote a scope which joins the `hits` table:

```
scope :with_hit_counts, -> {
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN hits ON hits.link_id = links.id").select('links.*', 'count(hits.link_id) AS hit_count').group("links.id")
}
```

This effectively adds a virtual `hit_count` attribute to each `Link`, which is computed in a single query. Curiously, it appears to be a separate query from loading the links, rather than actually being done in the same query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, links.id AS links_id
  FROM "links" LEFT OUTER JOIN hits ON hits.link_id = links.id
 WHERE "links"."user_id" = $1
 GROUP BY links.id
 ORDER BY "links"."domain_id" ASC, "links"."custom_slug" ASC, "links"."id" ASC ;
```

Unfortunately, as the `hits` table grows, this has become a slow query. `EXPLAIN` indicates that the query is joining *all* hits with their matching links using an index, and then narrowing the links down to just the ones with the correct `user_id` by sequential scan; that seems to be the reason it's slow. However, if we're already loading the list of links separately—and we are—there's no actual need to join the links table at all. We can get the list of link IDs for the user and then do a query purely on the hits table with `hits.link_id IN (list of IDs)`.

It's easy to write this as a separate query, and it runs lightning-fast:

```
Hit.where(link_id: @user.links.ids).group(:link_id).count
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to get ActiveRecord to do this as a scope on the `Link` model, so that each `Link` has a `hit_count` attribute I can use, and so that I can use the resulting return value as a relation with the ability to chain other queries onto it. Any ideas?

(I do know about ActiveRecord's `counter_cache` feature, but I don't want to use it here—`hits` are inserted by a separate, non-Ruby system, and modifying that system to update the counter cache would be moderately painful.)

Comment: Have you considered using a database view, and adding the hit_count attribute to it?  On the database level that's handled so much faster than on the activerecord level.

Answer (score 0):

As trh mentioned, the common way to go about this is to add a hits_count to link.rb  Then you can query and sort quickly.  You just have to keep them in sync.  If it truly is a basic count, then you can use the basic rails counter cache.  This will increment and decrement on create and destroy.

```
class AddCounterCacheToLink < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :links, :hits_count, :integer, :default => 0  

    Link.reset_column_information  
    Link.all.each do |l|  
      l.update_attribute :hits_count, l.hits.size
    end 
  end
end
```

And then in the model

```
class Hit < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :link, :counter_cache => true   #this will trigger the rails magic
```

If you have something more complicated, you can write your own, which is trivial.